# tcl tk binding virtual events for tabs

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to bind an event to a tab opening in a tcl tk application.
I've gotten the virtual event NotebookTabChanged to bind to anytime a tab is changed, however I do not know how to get the tab that was selected.

Below is the idea of what I want to do.  Obviously, its not real tcl tk code.

```
ttk::notebook .gui.tframe3.tpanedwindow4.notebook0
bind .gui.tframe3.tpanedwindow4.notebook0 <<NotebookTabChanged>> {GUITabOpen %w}
ttk::frame .gui.tframe3.tpanedwindow4.notebook0.tframe1  -borderwidth {0}  -relief {flat}  -width {30}  -height {30}
...
proc GUITabOpen { {w 0} } {
if {##The tab selected is tframe1###} {
#do some action related to tframe1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only useful information in the `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` virtual event is what `ttk::notebook` widget it is talking about (the `%W` substitution, *capital* W). To find out what tab is the new *current* tab, you've got to ask the widget in the event.

```
$theNotebookWidget index current
```

Though to get the name of the widget associated with the current tab, you *actually* use the `select` method without further arguments:

```
$theNotebookWidget select
```

From [the manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_notebook.htm):

> *pathname* **select** ?*tabid*?
>   Selects the specified tab. The associated slave window will be displayed, and the previously-selected window (if different) is unmapped. If *tabid* is omitted, returns the widget name of the currently selected pane.